# Azure machine learning failing on sample for training

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run below sample code in my notebook, Running on python 3.6 kernel.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-train-models-with-aml
Download the MNIST dataset

The following code failed with the attribute error, on line of the following code from azureml.opendatasets import MNIST

```
from azureml.core import Dataset
from azureml.opendatasets import MNIST
```

Comment: Please post the exact text of the error message, and the complete code. You're missing an `import os` in the code given, for example.

Comment: Full error needed, and remove any of the python code after the error is thrown for brevity

Comment: Can you please add more details of Azure ML SDK version that you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prerequisites:
The tutorial and accompanying utils.py file is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/tutorials) if you wish to use it on your own [local environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-environment#local). Run pip install azureml-sdk[notebooks] azureml-opendatasets matplotlib to install dependencies for this tutorial.

If you are using older version then upgrade to the latest Azure ML SDK Version 1.0.85.

!pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk

```
# check core SDK version number
print("Azure ML SDK Version: ", azureml.core.VERSION)
```

Also

!pip install --upgrade azureml-opendataset